# gparted ntfs partition mountable but can't resize

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ntfs, 18.04

Trying to dual-boot install 18.04 on a machine with Windows 10 already installed.   The installer didn't give me the option to shrink windows and dual-boot, so I went to manually repartition.

I tried to shrink the existing Windows 10 NTFS partition in gparted but there's an exclamation mark with a warning.

[image: gparted showing exclamation mark next to ntfs partition]

The warning says that it needs ntfs-3g installed, but it already is.

[image: dialog showing information on partition with ntfs-3g error]

gparted says its installed and can shrink.

[image: gparted filesystem support showing ntfs-3g loaded and supporting shrink]

I made sure that Windows had fast startup disabled and had been shut down properly.

I also ran `chkdsk /f C:` and rebooted and then shut down properly before trying again.

And to prove that it's able to load, I manually mounted the partition!

I also tried resizing with `gnome-disks` but it goes grey as though it's opening a dialog and freezes until I press alt-F4.

So, in summary:

- ntfs-3g enabled
- Windows fastboot disabled
- `chkdsk /f C:` successful
- Windows shut down properly (no hibernate)
- partition mountable from Ubuntu

**What else could be stopping it from being able to be shrunk?**

Comment: The first noticeable thing is that there appears to be no usage of sda4. I would expect to see some if you have W10 in there. It's possibly been corrupted. Can you mount sda4, then run command `df -h` and tell us if it shows any usage?

Comment: @PaulBenson Yes, the mount correctly shows 37GB of usage with 202GB free and Windows 10 runs correctly.  I would expect if the partition were corrupted, then `chkdsk /f C:` on Windows would have shown there to be errors.

Comment: That is really odd, because gparted is showing sda4 as an unused partition, whereas `df` shows things correctly.

Did you mount sda4 from gparted? Have you tried viewing sda and its partitions in `Disks`? Once you've mounted sda4 does it show correctly in there? Do you have the partition show as a drive in the Launcher bar? Can you see/open  the Windows folders and files without error from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

### Use Windows tools to shrink the Windows partition

- I suggest that you **boot into Windows**, and use the tools available there to shrink the Windows partition.
- Do not create any new partition (because Windows will probably create a dynamic partition, which cannot be used by linux). Instead you should leave unallocated drive space.
- Boot into Ubuntu live and use **`gparted`** to create a partition or partitions, that can be used by Ubuntu.

Comment: Last time I checked, you can't change the partition you booted from in Windows.  Has this changed?

Comment: I think you checked very long ago. This has been possible for several years.

Comment: This worked well for me, after a couple failed attempts to do it on the linux side after shutting down windows

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the file system is in an inconsistent state and this would prevent the file system from being resized.  This commonly happens if Windows was not shutdown properly (e.g., powered off, or hibernated).

The fix is to boot into Windows and perform a proper shutdown.  Then boot from live media containing GParted (such as [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)) which should not mount any of the partitions.  Then try the resize again.

Further be sure that Windows Dynamic Disks are not being used as these are not supported.

Comment: I'm running this from an Ubuntu 18.04 USB Boot Disk.  Your first 2 points are discounted by Point 3 - "chkdsk /f successful" and Point 4 - "Windows was properly shut down (No hibernate)".  I will check on the dynamic disks, but I would be really surprised if I chose that as an option.

Comment: GParted uses a command similar to the following to determine the used/unused sectors in an NTFS file system: `sudo ntfsresize --info --force --no-progress-bar /dev/sda4` . You might try running the command from a terminal window to see if it reports any errors that might indicate the source of the problem

Answer (score -1):

It possible to run the live installation in trial mode before attempting to use gparted.

then you can use a terminal to run `ntfsfix /dev/sda4` to repair the ntfs partition.

you can now use gparted to resize the partition and create a new one.

Comment: We've already established that the ntfs partition does not have any errors, so ntfsfix won't solve this problem.